# Cryptocurrency - parser error on Smart Contact final line?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency

I have been working on a smart contract for a cryptocurrency over the past few hours and was getting ready to compile it. But when it was time to compile it, I got a error from Solidity stating: " ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition." It's on the final line, and I've checked the whole code multiple times to see no error. Any help would be great. Code is below:

```js
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

// File: zepplin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol

contract Ownable {
    address public owner;
    
    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner,
    address indexed newOwner);
    
// @dev The Ownable constructor sets the original 'owner' of the contract to the sender
// account.

function Ownable() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

// if any other account besides owner

modifier onlyOwner() {
    requir(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

// to transfer ownership in case of event 

function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner 
{
    require(newOwner != address(0));
    OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
    owner = newOwner;
}

}
// Safemath protocol

library SafeMath {
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns 
    (uint256) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        uint256 c = a * b;
        assert(c / a == b);
        return c; 
    }
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns
    (uint256) {
        // assrt(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
        uint256 c = a / b; 
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
        return c;
    }
    function sub(unit256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns 
    (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b; 
    }
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns
    (uint256) {
        uint256 c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
}

// Smart contract title (ERC20)

contract ERC20 {
    uint256 public totalSupply;
  function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);

  function transfer (address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256);
  
  function transferFrom(addres from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
  
  event approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
    
}
contract HepburnA is ERC20, Ownable {
     using SafeMath for uint256; 
     
     // the controller of minting and destroying tokens
     address public hepburnDevmoon = 
     0x471E918a75A99038856eF9754368Eb1b5D15f9D5;
     
     // the controller of approving of minting and withdraw tokens 
     address public hepburnCommunitymoon = 
     0x0554c3CF2315FB98181d1FEBfaf083cDf68Fa145;
     
     struct TokensWithLock{
         uint256 value;
         uint256 blockNumber;
         
     }
     //Balances (shared with ERC20Basic replicant)
     mapping(address => uint256) balances;
     //When token numbers is less than incoming block
     mapping(address => TokenswithLock) lockTokens;
     
     mapping(address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed; 
     // Token Cap
     uint256 public totalSupplyCap = 1e11;
     // Token Info
     string public name = "Hepburn A";
     string public symbol = "AUYHA";
     uint8 public decimals = 18;
     
     bool public mintingFinished = false;
     // the block number when deploy
     uint256 public deployBlockNumber = getCurrentBlockNumber();
     // the min threshold of lock time 
     uint256 public constant TIMETHRESHOLD = 9720;
     // the time when mintTokensWithinTime can be called 
     uint256 public constant MINTTIME = 291600;
     // the lock time of minted tokens 
     uint256 public durationOfLock = 9720;
     // True if transfers are allowed 
     bool public transferable = false; 
     // True if the transferable can be change 
     bool public canSetTransferable = true;
     
     modifier canMint() {
         require(!mintingFinished);
         _;
     }
     
     modifier only(address _address) {
         require(msg.sender == _address);
         _;
     }
     
     modifier nonZeroAddress(address _address) {
         require(_address != address(0));
         _;
     }
     
     modifier canTransfer() {
         require(transferable == true);
     }
     
     event SetDurationOfLock(address indexed _caller);
     event ApproveMintTokens(address indexed _owner, uint256 _amount);
     event WithdrawMintTokens(address indexed _owner, uint256 _amount);
     event MintTokens(address indexed _owner, uint256 _amount);
     event BurnTokens(address indexed _owner, uint256 _amount);
     event MintFinished(address indexed _caller);
     event setTransferable(address indexed _address, bool _transferable);
     event SethepburnDevmoon(address indexed _old, address indexed _new);
     event DisableSetTransferable(ddress indexed _address, bool _canSetTransferable);
     
     function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) canTransfer public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);

    // SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Gets the balance of the specified address.
   * @param _owner The address to query the the balance of.
   * @return An uint256 representing the amount owned by the passed address.
   */
  function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) 
  {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens from one address to another
   * @param _from address The address which you want to send tokens from
   * @param _to address The address which you want to transfer to
   * @param _value uint256 the amount of tokens to be transferred
   */
  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) canTransfer public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[_from]);
    require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
    Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Approve the passed address to spend the specified amount of tokens on behalf of msg.sender.
   *
   * Beware that changing an allowance with this method brings the risk that someone may use both the old
   * and the new allowance by unfortunate transaction ordering. One possible solution to mitigate this
   * race condition is to first reduce the spender's allowance to 0 and set the desired value afterwards:
   * https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/20#issuecomment-263524729
   * @param _spender The address which will spend the funds.
   * @param _value The amount of tokens to be spent.
   */
  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) canTransfer public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Function to check the amount of tokens that an owner allowed to a spender.
   * @param _owner address The address which owns the funds.
   * @param _spender address The address which will spend the funds.
   * @return A uint256 specifying the amount of tokens still available for the spender.
   */
  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

  /**
   * approve should be called when allowed[_spender] == 0. To increment
   * allowed value is better to use this function to avoid 2 calls (and wait until
   * the first transaction is mined)
   * From MonolithDAO Token.sol
   */
  function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint256 _addedValue) canTransfer public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue);
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

  function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint256 _subtractedValue) canTransfer public returns (bool) {
    uint256 oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
    if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
    } else {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
    }
    Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }
  /**
   * @dev Enables token holders to transfer their tokens freely if true
   * @param _transferable True if transfers are allowed
   */
  function setTransferable(bool _transferable) only(hepburnDevmoon) public {
    require(canSetTransferable == true);
    transferable = _transferable;
    SetTransferable(msg.sender, _transferable);
  }

  /**
   * @dev disable the canSetTransferable
   */
  function disableSetTransferable() only(hepburnDevmoon) public {
    transferable = true;
    canSetTransferable = false;
    DisableSetTransferable(msg.sender, false);
  }

  /**
   * @dev Set the hepburnDevmoon
   * @param _hepburnDevmoon The new hepburnDevmoon
   */
  function SethepburnDevmoon(address _hepburnDevmoon) only(hepburnDevmoon) nonZeroAddress(_hepburnDevmoon) public {
   hepburnDevmoon = _hepburnDevmoon;
    SethepburnDevmoon(msg.sender, _hepburnDevmoon);
  }
  /**
   * @dev Set the hepburnCommunitymoon
   * @param _hepburnCommunitymoon The new hepburnCommunitymoon
   */
  function sethepburnCommunitymoon(address _hepburnCommunitymoon) only(hepburnCommunitymoon) nonZeroAddress(_hepburnCommunitymoon) public {
   hepburnCommunitymoon = _hepburnCommunitymoon;
    sethepburnCommunitymoon(msg.sender, _hepburnCommunitymoon);
  }
  /**
   * @dev Set the duration of lock of tokens approved of minting
   * @param _durationOfLock the new duration of lock
   */
  function setDurationOfLock(uint256 _durationOfLock) canMint only(hepburnCommunitymoon) public {
    require(_durationOfLock >= TIMETHRESHOLD);
    durationOfLock = _durationOfLock;
    SetDurationOfLock(msg.sender);
  }
  /**
   * @dev Get the quantity of locked tokens
   * @param _owner The address of locked tokens
   * @return the quantity and the lock time of locked tokens
   */
   function getLockTokens(address _owner) nonZeroAddress(_owner) view public returns (uint256 value, uint256 blockNumber) {
     return (lockTokens[_owner].value, lockTokens[_owner].blockNumber);
   }

  /**
   * @dev Approve of minting `_amount` tokens that are assigned to `_owner`
   * @param _owner The address that will be assigned the new tokens
   * @param _amount The quantity of tokens approved of mintting
   * @return True if the tokens are approved of mintting correctly
   */
  function approveMintTokens(address _owner, uint256 _amount) nonZeroAddress(_owner) canMint only(hepburnCommunitymoon) public returns (bool) {
    require(_amount > 0);
    uint256 previousLockTokens = lockTokens[_owner].value;
    require(previousLockTokens + _amount >= previousLockTokens);
    uint256 curTotalSupply = totalSupply;
    require(curTotalSupply + _amount >= curTotalSupply); // Check for overflow
    require(curTotalSupply + _amount <= totalSupplyCap);  // Check for overflow of total supply cap
    uint256 previousBalanceTo = balanceOf(_owner);
    require(previousBalanceTo + _amount >= previousBalanceTo); // Check for overflow
    lockTokens[_owner].value = previousLockTokens.add(_amount);
    uint256 curBlockNumber = getCurrentBlockNumber();
    lockTokens[_owner].blockNumber = curBlockNumber.add(durationOfLock);
    ApproveMintTokens(_owner, _amount);
    return true;
  }
  /**
   * @dev Withdraw approval of minting `_amount` tokens that are assigned to `_owner`
   * @param _owner The address that will be withdrawn the tokens
   * @param _amount The quantity of tokens withdrawn approval of mintting
   * @return True if the tokens are withdrawn correctly
   */
  function withdrawMintTokens(address _owner, uint256 _amount) nonZeroAddress(_owner) canMint only(hepburnCommunitymoon) public returns (bool) {
    require(_amount > 0);
    uint256 previousLockTokens = lockTokens[_owner].value;
    require(previousLockTokens - _amount >= 0);
    lockTokens[_owner].value = previousLockTokens.sub(_amount);
    if (previousLockTokens - _amount == 0) {
      lockTokens[_owner].blockNumber = 0;
    }
    WithdrawMintTokens(_owner, _amount);
    return true;
  }
  /**
   * @dev Mints `_amount` tokens that are assigned to `_owner`
   * @param _owner The address that will be assigned the new tokens
   * @return True if the tokens are minted correctly
   */
  function mintTokens(address _owner) canMint only(hepburnDevmoon) nonZeroAddress(_owner) public returns (bool) {
    require(lockTokens[_owner].blockNumber <= getCurrentBlockNumber());
    uint256 _amount = lockTokens[_owner].value;
    uint256 curTotalSupply = totalSupply;
    require(curTotalSupply + _amount >= curTotalSupply); // Check for overflow
    require(curTotalSupply + _amount <= totalSupplyCap);  // Check for overflow of total supply cap
    uint256 previousBalanceTo = balanceOf(_owner);
    require(previousBalanceTo + _amount >= previousBalanceTo); // Check for overflow
    
    totalSupply = curTotalSupply.add(_amount);
    balances[_owner] = previousBalanceTo.add(_amount);
    lockTokens[_owner].value = 0;
    lockTokens[_owner].blockNumber = 0;
    MintTokens(_owner, _amount);
    Transfer(0, _owner, _amount);
    return true;
  }
  /**
   * @dev Mints `_amount` tokens that are assigned to `_owner` within one day after deployment
   * the tokens minted will be added to balance immediately
   * @param _owner The address that will be assigned the new tokens
   * @param _amount The quantity of tokens withdrawn minted
   * @return True if the tokens are minted correctly
   */
  function mintTokensWithinTime(address _owner, uint256 _amount) nonZeroAddress(_owner) canMint only(hepburnDevmoon) public returns (bool) {
    require(_amount > 0);
    require(getCurrentBlockNumber() < (deployBlockNumber + MINTTIME));
    uint256 curTotalSupply = totalSupply;
    require(curTotalSupply + _amount >= curTotalSupply); // Check for overflow
    require(curTotalSupply + _amount <= totalSupplyCap);  // Check for overflow of total supply cap
    uint256 previousBalanceTo = balanceOf(_owner);
    require(previousBalanceTo + _amount >= previousBalanceTo); // Check for overflow
    
    totalSupply = curTotalSupply.add(_amount);
    balances[_owner] = previousBalanceTo.add(_amount);
    MintTokens(_owner, _amount);
    Transfer(0, _owner, _amount);
    return true;
  }
  /**
   * @dev Transfer tokens to multiple addresses
   * @param _addresses The addresses that will receieve tokens
   * @param _amounts The quantity of tokens that will be transferred
   * @return True if the tokens are transferred correctly
   */
  function transferForMultiAddresses(address[] _addresses, uint256[] _amounts) canTransfer public returns (bool) {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _addresses.length; i++) {
      require(_addresses[i] != address(0));
      require(_amounts[i] <= balances[msg.sender]);
      require(_amounts[i] > 0);

      // SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
      balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_amounts[i]);
      balances[_addresses[i]] = balances[_addresses[i]].add(_amounts[i]);
      Transfer(msg.sender, _addresses[i], _amounts[i]);
    }
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * @dev Burns `_amount` tokens from `_owner`
   * @param _amount The quantity of tokens being burned
   * @return True if the tokens are burned correctly
   */
  function burnTokens(uint256 _amount) public returns (bool) {
    require(_amount > 0);
    uint256 curTotalSupply = totalSupply;
    require(curTotalSupply >= _amount);
    uint256 previousBalanceTo = balanceOf(msg.sender);
    require(previousBalanceTo >= _amount);
    totalSupply = curTotalSupply.sub(_amount);
    balances[msg.sender] = previousBalanceTo.sub(_amount);
    BurnTokens(msg.sender, _amount);
    Transfer(msg.sender, 0, _amount);
    return true;
  }
  /**
   * @dev Function to stop minting new tokens.
   * @return True if the operation was successful.
   */
  function finishMinting() only(hepburnDevmoon) canMint public returns (bool) {
    mintingFinished = true;
    MintFinished(msg.sender);
    return true;
  }

  function getCurrentBlockNumber() private view returns (uint256) {
    return block.number;
  }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two extra right curly brackets (`}`) at the end of the code. I think that is why you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Some Observations:

1. two extra right curly brackets at the end.
2. in modifier onlyOwner(), their is typo (requir -> require).
3. function sub(unit256 a) typo, (unit256 -> uint256).
4. address typo -> event DisableSetTransferable(ddress indexed _address,
   bool _canSetTransferable);
5. function transferFrom(addres from) typo, (addres -> address).
6. modifier canTransfer() should contain "_;".
7. function setTransferable -> try changing name of this function as it
   is same as the event name you are calling from inside. (and may be due
   to  prefix "set" in function name compiler can give error)
8. best practice if you call any function, call it with same name and
   same case
   (ex. approval not as Approval)
9. Call correct method SethepburnDevmoon not sethepburnCommunitymoon
   inside function sethepburnCommunitymoon.
10. whenever you invoking any event, you should invoke it by adding prefix
    "emit" to it.
11. The GAS used by this contract at deployment will be almost 3800000 ->
    0.07562 eth -> almost $210 (in case you wanna know) -happy coding :)

Comment: Great attention to detail! ... Just a factual note to your point 10: In the 0.4 (deprecated) version of Solidity, that the OP is using, events are emitted without the `emit` expression, so this snippet is actually correct.